# Reducing script execution time

Tags: sql-server, ssas, business-intelligence, ssas-tabular

We have two Fact tables as below

Fact1

| DeviceKey | DateKey | TimeKey | CustomersIn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20230225 | 235612 | 2 |
| 1 | 20230226 | 94123 | 1 |
| 1 | 20230227 | 183408 | 3 |
| 1 | 20230228 | 175926 | 2 |
| 1 | 20230301 | 112319 | 1 |
| 2 | 20230225 | 224623 | 3 |
| 2 | 20230226 | 163452 | 2 |
| 3 | 20230225 | 45603 | 1 |
| 3 | 20230227 | 223451 | 2 |

Fact2

| DeviceKey | EventDatekey | EventTimeKey | ErrorKey |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20230225 | 81625 | 2 |
| 1 | 20230227 | 135409 | 2 |
| 1 | 20230301 | 124143 | 12 |
| 2 | 20230225 | 192324 | 2 |
| 2 | 20230226 | 180732 | 2 |
| 2 | 20230228 | 143919 | 12 |
| 2 | 20230301 | 71452 | 2 |
| 3 | 20230227 | 213451 | 2 |
| 3 | 20230228 | 212451 | 2 |

Display the EventDateKey and EventTimeKey of Fact 2 table, which is greater than the maximum Datekey and TimeKey for each device in Fact 1 table. If two days or 48 hours have passed from the maximum DateKey and TimeKey for each device in Fact 1 table.
Right now, date and time: 2023/03/01 11:58

Result

| DeviceKey | EventDatekey | EventTimeKey | ErrorKey | maxdatetimeKey |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 20230226 | 180732 | 2 | 20230226163452 |
| 2 | 20230228 | 143919 | 12 | 20230226163452 |
| 2 | 20230301 | 71452 | 2 | 20230226163452 |
| 3 | 20230228 | 212451 | 2 | 20230227223451 |

I used this script

```
SELECT f2.*, s.maxdatetimekey
FROM Fact2 f2
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT DeviceKey, MAX(CONCAT(DateKey, FORMAT(TimeKey, '0#####'))) as maxdatetimeKey
  FROM FactTelemetry f1
  GROUP BY DeviceKey
) s ON s.DeviceKey = f2.DeviceKey AND CONCAT(EventDateKey, FORMAT(EventTimeKey, '0#####')) > maxdatetimeKey;
GO
```

But this is a simple example of our data and the amount of our data is very large, which makes the execution of this script take a long time, what do you suggest to solve this problem?

Comment: Store dates and times as date/time/datetime. Your join criteria is not sargable, in addition `format` is known to perform badly.

Comment: I have date in one DIM table and Time in another DIM table, so I have two separate columns for each.
I think I did not understand exactly what you mean
Can you explain with an example?

Comment: What field type are you using for your EventDateKey, EventTimeKey and MaxDatetimeKey? Are they integers? Do you have a calendar dimension?

Comment: Its format is int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I would try would be to change your join and maxdatetimekey:

```
    SELECT f2.*, s.maxdatetimekey
    FROM Fact2 f2
    INNER JOIN (
      SELECT DeviceKey, MAX(CAST(DateKey as bigint) * 1000000 + TimeKey) as MaxDateTimeKey
--, MAX(CONCAT(DateKey, FORMAT(TimeKey, '0#####'))) as maxdatetimeKey

      FROM FactTelemetry f1
      GROUP BY DeviceKey
    ) s ON s.DeviceKey = f2.DeviceKey AND 
    CAST(EventDateKey as bigint) * 1000000 + EventTimeKey > = maxdatetimeKey
    --CONCAT(EventDateKey, FORMAT(EventTimeKey, '0#####')) > maxdatetimeKey;
    ;
```

See if that helps.

Comment: If we use this code, it will not work correctly for the case where TimeKey contains 5 characters or less. For example, TimeKey = 94123 and DateKey = 20230226, and the result is 2023022600000094123.

Comment: 20230226 * 1000000 + 94123 = 2030229094123

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really understand what a good idea it is, but there is a problem when we run it: Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

Comment: Where? In the derived table or the join clause? Are all three fields integers? I will guess not if you are getting this error.

Comment: It was fixed by casting DateKey and BIGINT.

Comment: Does that make your script run fast enough?